# Ubuntu sleeps when power cable is removed

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, battery

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Macbook 5,2. It works fairly well except that when the power cable is unplugged the desktop logs out, prompting the password menu and in less than a second the computer goes to sleep.

Sometimes it wont wake up unless I reattach the power cable. The battery is in healthy condition and it takes an hour to deplete in Ubuntu and other Distros.

Im confident to say its caused by Ubuntu software.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not standard behaviour for 14.04. One thing that might help is changing the Brightness & Display settings in System Settings, and setting the screen to not lock. Not sure if this will help, but it is where I would start.

Comment: Will the computer start up OK if only connected to battery power?

Comment: Yes @user3169 the computer can wake up and turn on with only the battery.